# How can I turn off unwanted labels without losing street names in satellite view?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-labels

I want to use Google Maps in **Satelite** view, but the only **labels** I want displayed are the street names.

I want to exclude all other **labels** such as business names, points of interest, gas stations, restaurants, parking lots, and hotels because they obscure my view of the map.

If I uncheck the **`Labels`** option found by clicking **`Layers > More`** it removes the unnecessary clutter but it also removes the street names.

[image: Toggle 'Labels' option in 'Layers > More']

How can I hide the unwanted **labels** in **Satellite** view without also losing the street names?

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately, this is not possible in:

- https://www.google.com/maps/
- https://www.google.com/maps/d/

[image]

but possible in:

- https://earth.google.com/web/@
- https://www.google.com/intl/en/earth/desktop/

and with some tune-ups, you can then create a custom map which you can then export as KML and import to MyMaps from where you can view it as it would be on google.com/maps/

[image]